# android: internal files reading

Tags: java, android, file

I'm trying to write some data into internal storage. Problem is when I read it. It does not read nothing. Logcat says it writes something in it. But when I read it Log cat says its empty. This is my File manager:

```
public class FileManager {  
    File dir;
    File driveFile;
    BufferedWriter writer=null;
    BufferedReader reader=null;

    public FileManager(Context context,String name){
        dir = new File(context.getFilesDir(),"drives");
        dir.mkdirs();
        driveFile = new File(dir,name+".txt");
        Log.d("FileManager",driveFile.getAbsolutePath());
    }

    public void open() throws IOException{
        writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(driveFile));
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(driveFile));
    }

    public void close() throws IOException{
        writer.close();
        reader.close();
    }

    public boolean writeTrackPoints(Drive drive){
        TrackPoint [] trackPoints=drive.getTrackPoints();
        Log.d("FileManager", "writing....");
        for(int i=0;i<trackPoints.length;i++){
            try {
                String line = trackPoints[i].getParsingString()+"\r\n";
                writer.write(line);
                writer.flush();
                Log.d("FileManager", "Writing" + line);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return false;
            }           
        }       
        return true;
    }

    public boolean readTrackPoints(Drive drive){
        String line=null;
        Log.d("FileManager", "reading....");
        try {
            while((line = reader.readLine())!=null){
                Log.d("FileManager", "Reading: "+line);
                drive.addTrackPoint(new TrackPoint(line));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("FileManager", e.getMessage());
            return false;
        }       
        return true;
    }
}
```

I cant check if file is empty because my device is not rooted. I recognize it does not step into while cyclus in reading. Isn't problem that I open both streams at once?

Comment: Doing at the same time reading and writing is not possible via BufferedReader/BufferedWriter. Either do for every access a new instance, opening and closing the file, or use another mechanism.

Comment: Sometimes you're swallowing exceptions, and sometimes you're just logging the message instead of the full stack trace. In both cases you're catching the exception when you should let the caller do that - your IO methods should declare that they throw `IOException`, and *not* try to handle the exception.

Comment: Joop Eggen: I create new instance when im writing, then I close it create new instance for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved it. Problem was in methods open/close. Maybe it isn't possible to open both streams in one moment. This is edited FileManager:

```
public class FileManager {

    File dir;
    File driveFile;
    BufferedWriter writer=null;
    BufferedReader reader=null;
    public FileManager(Context context,String name){
        dir = new File(context.getFilesDir(),"drives");
        dir.mkdirs();
        driveFile = new File(dir,name+".txt");
        Log.d("FileManager",driveFile.getAbsolutePath());
    }

    public void writeTrackPoints(Drive drive) throws IOException{
        writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(driveFile));
        TrackPoint [] trackPoints=drive.getTrackPoints();
        for(int i=0;i<trackPoints.length;i++){
            String line = trackPoints[i].getParsingString()+"\r\n";
            writer.write(line);
            writer.flush();
        }
        writer.close();
    }

    public void readTrackPoints(Drive drive) throws IOException{
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(driveFile));
        String line=null;
        while((line = reader.readLine())!=null){
            drive.addTrackPoint(new TrackPoint(line));
        }
        reader.close();
    }
}
```